# using animations.css for animating

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to use animations.css and css3-animate-it.js for making some interesting animations. It is very simple  to use and saves  lots of time. but when using these files the css file makes my page scroll  horizontally.I can't understand why it happens. I only know for sure that it is because of css file.Who have used these files and know the reason?Here is my code:

```
    <div class="description">   
            <div class="general">
                 <div class="animatedParent"> 
                     <div class='animated bounceInDown'> 
                        <h2>General</h2>
                        <p> This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. 
                        Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean     sollicitudin, 
                        lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit.
                        Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
                        Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat 
                        auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
                        </p>
                        <button  onclick="show()">MORE...</button>                  
                    </div>
                 </div> 
         </div> 


        <div class="religion">
                <div class="animatedParent"> 
                    <div class='animated bounceInUp'> 
                        <h2>Religion</h2>
                        <p> This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. 
                        Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, 
                        lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit.
                        Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
                        Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat 
                        auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia</p>
                        <button>MORE...</button> 
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="location">
                 <div class="animatedParent"> 
                     <div class='animated bounceInDown'> 
                        <h2>Location</h2>
                        <p> This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. 
                        Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, 
                        lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit.
                        Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
                        Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat 
                        auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia</p>
                        <button>MORE...</button>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

 .description{width:1320px;height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;}

 .description>div{float:left;}
.general,
.religion,
.location{width:32%;margin:5px;padding-top:30px;background: rgb(245, 245,      242);}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: If your page is less than 1320px, the page will scroll horixontally because `.description` has a width of 1320px. You could make that `max-width` and see if that helps.